# What is meant by equal chemical environment in NMR?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I am studying NMR and the concept of chemical equivalence is confusing. What does it mean exactly? Does it involve having different atoms to the left, right, up and down of a particular hydrogen in question? Please explain. Also I don't understand diastereotopic hydrogen give two shift? Like wouldn't rotating the bonds give same chemical environment to the two hydrogen giving them one signal. I am confused.

Comment: Homotopic, Enantiotopic, Diastereotopic - http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/04/17/homotopic-enantiotopic-diastereotopic/

Comment: In reference to NMR, *chemical environment* would be something that causes H peak to shift or split.

Comment: Chemical and Magnetic Equivalence - http://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.com/2008/08/chemical-and-magnetic-equivalence.html

Comment: The two questions are only mildly related; you should separate them into two different questions. Incidentally, I’m sure the diastereotopic-hydrogens-two-signals-question has been asked before on here.